# Gridlayout on nativescript doesn't strech the components

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to make the grid layout on  nativescript work but I am getting this result:

[image]

Here is my XML

```
<Page class="page" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" actionBarHidden="true">

    <StackLayout class="p-5">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <GridLayout rows="*, *" columns="50%,40%,10%" width="100%" backgroundColor="#888">
                    <Label text="option" class="h2 m-y-auto" width="100%" textWrap="true" row="0" col="0" backgroundColor="#f00" />
                    <Label text="value" class="h2 text-primary m-y-auto" width="100%" row="0" col="1" backgroundColor="#0f0" />
                    <Button text="U" tap="{{openData}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-active p-0 m-0" width="100%" row="0" col="2" backgroundColor="#00f" />
                    <Button text="D" tap="{{openData}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-active p-0 m-0" width="100%" row="1" col="2" backgroundColor="#ff0" />
                </GridLayout>

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: What is your *desired* result ?

Comment: please add playground demo

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer in the documentation, thanks!!

```
<GridLayout rows="*,*" columns="2*,2*,*" width="100%" backgroundColor="#888">
                <Label text="option" class="h2 m-y-auto" width="100%" textWrap="true" row="0" col="0" rowSpan="2" backgroundColor="#f00" />
                <Label text="value" class="h2 text-primary m-y-auto" width="100%" row="0" col="1" rowSpan="2" backgroundColor="#0f0" />
                <Button text="U" tap="{{openData}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-active p-0 m-0" width="100%" row="0" col="2" backgroundColor="#00f" />
                <Button text="D" tap="{{openData}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-active p-0 m-0" width="100%" row="1" col="2" backgroundColor="#ff0" />
            </GridLayout>
```

[image]